# "Hello World" using OpenOffice 3 sample code

Tags: openoffice.org

I am trying to program a simple "Hello World" window on WinXP MSVC 2008.NET using [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) 3.0 API and SDK.

The article is big for beginners... http://api.openoffice.org/docs/DevelopersGuide/OfficeDev/OfficeDev.xhtml#1_1_OpenOffice.org_Application_Environment

What would the code for "Hello World" look like?

Comment: @aiw33k: what language should it be in? JavaScript, Python, Java, C#, VB.NET, OOo Basic?

Comment: C# would be perfect for me. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Setup your solution: http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/net-working-with-openoffice-3/

Then simple example: (http://opendocument4all.com/content/view/68/47/)

```
using  System;
// Add all needed CLI namespaces to the current class.
using unoidl.com.sun.star.lang;  
using unoidl.com.sun.star.uno;  
using unoidl.com.sun.star.bridge;  
using unoidl.com.sun.star.frame;  

namespace OOTutorial
{ 
    class OpenOfficeApp
    { 
        //Define a file name. Change this to an existing path!  
        private static string FileName = @"F:\odtfiles   est.odt";

        [STAThread] 
        static void Main( string [] args)  
        {
            //Call the bootstrap method to get a new ComponentContext  
            //object. If OpenOffice isn't already started this will
            //start it and then return the ComponentContext.
            unoidl.com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext localContext =         
                uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap(); 

            //Get a new service manager of the MultiServiceFactory type  
            //we need this to get a desktop object and create new CLI  
            //objects.  
            unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory multiServiceFactory =  
                (unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory)
                localContext.getServiceManager();

            //Create a new Desktop instance using our service manager  
            //Notice: We cast our desktop object to XComponent loader  
            //so that we could load or create new documents.  
            XComponentLoader componentLoader = 
                (XComponentLoader) 
                multiServiceFactory.createInstance(  "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop" ); 

            //Create a new blank writer document using our component  
            //loader object.  
            XComponent xComponent = componentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(   
                "private:factory/swriter",    //a blank writer document  
                "_blank", 0,       //into a blank frame use no searchflag  
                //use no additional arguments.  
                new unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0]); 

            //Cast our component to a the XText interface  

            //and write some simple text into document.                  
            ((unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)xComponent). 
                getText().setString("Hello I'm the first text!"); 

            //After we insert our text, we cast our component to XStorable  
            //to save it onto the harddisk  
            ((XStorable)xComponent).storeToURL( 
                //Convert the file path into a OpenOffice path  
                PathConverter(FileName), 
                //no additional arguments  
                new unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0]);  

            Console.WriteLine("Your first OpenOffice document is saved!"); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 

        ///  
        /// Convert into OO file format  
        ///  
        private static string PathConverter( string file)  
        { 
            try  
            { 
                file = file.Replace(@"\", "/"); 
                return "file:///"+file;  
            } 
            catch (System.Exception ex)  
            { 
                throw ex;  
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does this require an existing installation of OpenOffice on the system? Is calling on it the function `Bootstrap.bootsrap()` serves?