# UNO classes to VB .NET

Tags: openoffice-writer, uno

I've found some samples of OpenOffice UNO dll to try out with VB.NET, but I'm still having issues with it:

1. It doesn't want to compile with any version of .NET Framework over 2.0 (Which is at least 7 years old!)
2. Sample is very poor in functionalities, just insert some plain text without formating.

   Are there any specs or documentation available for UNO for .NET? C# or VB?
3. Has anyone had a good experience with OpenOffice Automation and .NET?

Comment: Post link to sample or show as your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used OpenOffice UNO SDK in my projects.

I posted hello world example in answer to this question ["Hello World" using OpenOffice 3 sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054328/hello-world-using-openoffice-3-sample-code/2511035#2511035)